# How to output compilation dependencies from CMake or make?

Tags: dependencies, makefile, cmake

I have a CMake C++ project that is rapidly growing and often changing. I'm trying to reduce compile times to a minimum.

Often, when I rebuild the project, especially after a header change, I'm surprised at how many compilation units need to be recompiled. I'm trying to identify `#include`s that can possibly be avoided, for example by using pre-declarations or by not inlining trivial functions in headers.

**Is there any way to find out, from CMake itself, from the generated Makefile, or directly from the files themselves, which units depend on which headers?**

A list would be nice, a visual graph (graphviz?) even nicer. Google turns up nothing for me. CMake has the `--graphviz` option, but it operates on targets, not individual compilation units.

Something cross-platform (i.e. using just CMake) is preferred, but I'll settle for Linux-only too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the dependency information generated by cmake2.8 (after running make) living in `depend.make` and `depend.internal` files, when I'm using a gcc based toolchain. Using VS does not seem to generate such files (but this doesn't seem to be a problem for you). Also these files are cmake internals, **so use them at your own risk**.

Comment: This is only the transitive closure (i.e. including indirect dependencies), but it's helpful, thanks!